# Using "tornado.httpclient" fetch "POST https" site get "HTTPError: HTTP 599"

Tags: python, httpclient, httprequest, tornado, urllib

I want to use "tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient" to send a "POST" request to a "https" website, but get:

```
HTTPError: HTTP 599: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

It works when I use "urllib" instead(with same url and parameters,headers I don't know)
code like this:

```
url = r'https://**********.com/****/'
request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url = url, method = 'POST', body = body, headers = headers)
client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
client.fetch(request, callback = on_reqeust)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Your python version `> 2.6`? If not - try `client.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")` before fetch.

Comment: Then try `client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)`..

Comment: seems it not recives that arg.it's an arg in httplib2,and I didn't see  somewhere tornado using it.But I think u r right, somehow set this

Comment: oops,I found it,see answer

Comment: I don't know this answer stuff,y don't u answer in 'Answer'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=url, method='POST', body=body,
                                         validate_cert=False)
```

add "validate_cert=False" when gen a http request
and seems no need to use curl_httpclient:

```
#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")
```

Comment: Note that if you ignore SSL cert validity, there is no point in using HTTPS instead of HTTP (no additional security) - so the proper solution would be to fix the certificate problem. YMMV of course.

Comment: Though the certificate may be invalid but the communication will still be happening over an encrypted ssl channel.

Comment: @tigeronk2, true, but an encrypted communication is pointless if an attacker can present a fake/tampered certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can also update CA certificates file used by SimpleAsyncHTTPClient.
It should be located in

`site-packages/tornado/ca-certificates.crt`

In my case copying file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to tornado location solved the problem.

Note: it will help in case if you have valid certificate but your Certificate Authority is not recognised by tornado.